# web page colors render review question unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, review-queue

I tried reviewing on meta for the first time today and was faced with this:

[image: unreadable review question]

Nearly white text on a nearly white background seems a poor choice.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing here, under Firefox 17.0.1.

Comment: Firefox 17.0.1 for me as well.

Comment: Chrome Version 23.0.1271.101, Firefox 18.0, and Safari 6.0.2 / OSX 10.7 too. Definitely a CSS problem, not a browser glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We updated meta.scifi CSS to fix this issue. Sorry about that.

Comment: In the same vein, on http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IjAgl.png (I selected the text “0 need review”, in the next column “reviews today” is invisible)

Comment: @Emmett, there are several areas on the meta site here that need similar fixes: see [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/can-we-change-the-font-of-the-new-responses-in-meta-scifi-so-that-it-is-readab) question and its answer for lists of them.